# How to get to the secret blue rupee room?

Tags: zelda-link-to-the-past

When I was a kid I stumbled upon the secret blue rupee room in Legend of Zelda - A Link to the Past for the SNES. I was ridiculed at the time because I couldn't reproduce it. I remember in the dialog box that appears when you enter this room that it was placed there by someone called Chris Houlihan.

How do you get to this room in the game?

Comment: makes me sad that dorkly said this was the biggest easter egg of all time.  If the internet was as wide spread in the 90's as it is now none of these things would seem that astounding.

Comment: My brother called me mad because he didnt believe me. I knew it was true.

Comment: This brings back memories! I tried for hours as a kid to get back into this room after I ran into it once!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [Chris Houlihan room](http://www.zeldawiki.org/Chris_Houlihan_Room) is named after the winner of a contest Nintendo Power ran in 1990 to have your name in an unnamed upcoming game. The existence of this room remained a secret for many years after the game was released.

[image: The Chris Houlihan room]

The game is actually programmed to transport you to this room as a fallback condition whenever an error occurs entering a new area. This means while it's possible to randomly stumble upon it accidentally, it's an incredibly rare event. However, there are at least a few reproducible ways to reach the room. [The YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7i2AHjvPMg) [eldarerathis linked to](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23232/how-to-get-to-the-secret-blue-rupee-room/23234#23234) shows a few.

In the GBA port of LttP, the room data remains in the game, but it's no longer reachable without hacking the ROM. The Chris Houlihan reference was also removed from the text.

Comment: It was a BUG? I stumbled upon a bug? I'm a programmer, finding bugs is my job. I found a BUG at such young age! I should have earned a pat in the back and not a "ah, youre such a loonie!". Damn, bro! Love him to bits ;p

Answer (score 15):

There's actually several different ways of doing this, and someone put together a convenient [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7i2AHjvPMg&feature=related) that shows 5 different methods.

The basic premise is the same in all of the methods, and is based on the fact that the room is something of a failsafe. If a glitch or error occurs while Link is falling into a hole, he gets transported to the room to prevent the game from crashing. Similar things have existed in other games, like the ["I HAVE NO GREETING" bug](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Shivering:Glitches#I_HAVE_NO_GREETING.21) in Oblivion: Shivering Isles.

Also, for the curious, the room wasn't actually "placed" by Chris Houlihan. I can't find a completely authoritative source, but as [this Zeldawiki page](http://www.zeldawiki.org/Chris_Houlihan_Room) explains, Chris Houlihan won a contest in Nintendo Power with the prize being that his name would be put in a room in the game somewhere (other sites corroborate this).

Embedded video from above:

Answer (score 6):

Taken from: http://faqs.ign.com/articles/374/374271p1.html

> As far as I've read, there are a few
>   methods to gain access to the room. I
>   have  everyone at the Legend of Zelda:
>   A Link to the Past message board at 
>   GameFAQs.com to thank for this
>   information! THANKS GUYS! I hope this
>   FAQ pays  tribute to all of your hard
>   work and effort to bring this secret
>   out.
>
> NOTE: To do any of these, you MUST
>   have the Pegasus Shoes, because you
>   HAVE to  run.
>
> The first method, and the one I use
>   the most often, and works the most
>   often  for me, is the following. Start
>   the game from a save file, and choose
>   to start  out at the Sanctuary. As the
>   game starts, you're within the walls
>   of the  Sanctuary. Immediately run
>   south, out of the Sanctuary, and then
>   south again,  out of the garden of the
>   Sanctuary. Then run west one screen,
>   and turn south as  soon as you can.
>   You'll now be in a heavily wooded
>   area. Carefully (and  quickly)
>   navigate the trees, bushes and
>   enemies, and head west, to the side 
>   passage into the castle walls. Once
>   here, run south, then east, and then
>   north.  Run north and run INTO the
>   bush that hides the hidden passage
>   into the castle  basement, and you'll
>   fall into it. If you're fast enough,
>   instead of falling  into the basement,
>   you'll fall into the Chris Houlihan
>   Room. Neat-o. Thanks to  a good guy at
>   the Zelda: LttP message boards, named
>   ABR. Thanks to him, this  FAQ is
>   possible, because his help turned me
>   on to this secret!
>
> The second method is similar. Go to
>   Kakariko village, to the vertical
>   pathway  on the east side of town, on
>   the edge of town. GO to the north of
>   it, and run  north. Run east, past the
>   Fortune Teller's house, and then run
>   south into the  wooded area. From
>   here, it's identical to the first
>   method... this version  never worked
>   for me, but coincidentally, this is
>   the version most people seem  to
>   successfully use, so I was probably
>   not fast enough. You may have
>   different  luck, however.
>
> Now for an unconfirmed method. Many
>   people say that if you fall into a
>   hole in  Ganon's Tower (e-mail me to
>   confirm WHICH hole), that you will
>   fall into the  Chris Houlihan Room.
>   This is unconfirmed.
>
> The fact of the matter is that the
>   room seems to be designed in such a
>   way that  if there's any malfunction
>   with the game cartridge, that it'll
>   automatically  transport you here.
>   David Wonn sites this one his site,
>   saying that the game  scans for
>   problems when entering caves and
>   houses, and if there is a  malfunction
>   with the cartridge, you will be
>   transported to the Chris Houlihan 
>   Room. This is confirmed, but very,
>   very rare. David Wonn says that you
>   have a  better chance of winning the
>   lottery than hitting it this way.

Videos:

Answer (score -1):

from a different user:

> What causes the game to load the Chris Houlihan's room is not yet entirely understood. It is believed that the room was intended as a failsafe; if there is a fatal error when the player changes rooms, the game dumps Link into the secret room. Most often it occurs when Link falls down into a hole leading to another area; it is known to be possible from the secret passage hole next to Hyrule Castle, the faery hole that's east of the cemetery, and *the hole on top of the Pyramid of Power* (where the final battle takes place). There are possibly other ways to enter the Chris Houlihan Room, but they are rare and do not work with any degree of accuracy.

The page was at [strategy wiki](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_A_Link_to_the_Past/Chris_Houlihan_Room) oh, and you can only access the room once after entered, or, **once per run**