# Chris Houlihan room in Link Between Worlds?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

In Zelda: A Link to the Past, there exists [a secret blue room](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/23232/42984).  Zelda: A Link Between
Worlds is a sequel to A Link to the Past.

Is the secret room from Link to the Past also in Link Between Worlds?

Answer (score 2):

As *A Link Between Worlds* is a sequel, not a remake, the secret room from ALTTP isn't present in ALBW. I've never seen evidence for the existence of any similar rooms, either, for that matter.

Comment: Yet it is in the same setting, so it would be reasonable to assume that such a secret room would be carried over for consistency.

Comment: @Waterseas: The Chris Houlihan room is an artifact of the room-loading code. It doesn't exist in-universe.

Comment: @3Doubloons It wasn't just an artifact, it was specifically put in as an 'error catching' room.

Comment: @Waterseas: That's what I meant. If the room-loading code didn't need a "Load this in case of error" room, the Houlihan room wouldn't exist. Hence, artifact.

Comment: @3Doubloons That doesn't mean they couldn't have put it in again as an easter egg and a reference to the prequel.